# "System cannot find the file specified" while creating a new MVC4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Opening visual studio 2012,
File > New Project > ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application, Razor as the view engine

- Error number: 0x80070002
- Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 & up-to-date

[image: error number 0x80070002]

**Edit:**
http://forums.asp.net/post/5373941.aspx
Didn't work.
Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I ran into this same error on VS2013.
Maybe this also works for vs2012

Run the NuGet.Tools.vsix.exe file under C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Visual Studio 12
Start vs2013 again and you should be able to create the mvc project.


Source:
Check under temporary solutions on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793578/cant-create-an-mvc4-project-in-visual-studio-2013-preview

Comment: Just curious - how on earth did you think to do that?

Comment: The NuGet team posted it as a temporary solution to the bug (linked in the awnser).

Comment: Same error here using VS2013, your fix worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading Asp.net & Web tools solved the problem.
AKA: Clicking "Get Everything in One Simple Install"
http://www.asp.net/downloads

Comment: I'm still getting this error after installing all components :9

please advice

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem after installing ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2. I solved it running repair mode from Visual Studio 2012 installation setup.